# Objective C: How do I make an NSMutableSet of NSMutableDictionaries, and have them be unique based on one of the dictionary values?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, set

The reason I'm asking this is because right now I use an NSMutableSet of integers and a corresponding NSMutableArray to store the rest of the data, but I think I'm not using the language right. Here's my code:

In the init function:

```
self.markerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.markerIdSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

And the function that updates the set and array:

```
- (void) addMarker: (RMMarker*)marker AtLatLong:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point {
  if (![self.markerIdSet member: [node objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
    [self.markerIdSet addObject:[node objectForKey:@"id"]];
    [self.markerList addObject:marker];
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be a bit wary of having a mutable object as part of a key in a set as if the object changes its hash code etc could change but the set would not know about it ( unless you make the addMarker remve the object and then add it back with the new hash code)

However in your example can't you just use a dictionary (or am I missing something?)

```
self.markerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

- (void) addMarker: (RMMarker*)marker AtLatLong:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point {
  if ([nil != [self.markerDict [node objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
      [self.markerDict setValue:marker forKey:[node objectForKey:@"id"]];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `NSMutableSet` contains unique elements. Uniqueness is determined by the `hash` and `isEquals` methods, so in order to do what you want, you should either subclass or delegate an `NSMutableDictionary` and in your own concrete class implement these methods so that the specific key you require is the equality and hash factor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make an `NSMutableSet` of `NSMutableDictionary` directly; make a custom class that has an `NSMutableDictionary` property. This custom class should implement [`-isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) and [`-hash`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) in terms of your id—i.e. this object will be equal to another object if the ids are equal, and two objects with the same id will have the same hash.

[More documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/FrameworkImpl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001286-1007347) with regard to `-isEqual:` and `-hash`.